# Unable to figure out how to work with Spring Data REST endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am getting this as response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-15T06:39:29.174+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/users"
}
```

when I am sending `GET` request at:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users
```

endpoint with following `@RepositoryRestResource`:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "api/users", path = "api/users")
public interface UserRestRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

with `dependencies`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Question is what is missing in my configuration above? Is there any other setting for working with Spring Data REST?

I am totally new to the world of Spring Data REST.

Comment: try collectionResourceRel = "/api/users", path = "/api/users"    Note the extra / before the paths

Comment: Not working :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your configurations looks OK, but your issue may be resolved by appending just:

```
# ************************************
#   For Spring Data REST Base Path   #
#*************************************
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

Into your `application.properties` file.

There is no need of adding `api/` or `/api/` in `collectionResourceRel` and `path` just:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
```

Is enough. Hope it resolves your issue.

Happy Coding!